# What does "arithmetical order" mean in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Model objects in the Python package scikit-learn have methods (e.g. predict_log_proba()) that return a probability/class matrix where classes are "ordered by arithmetical order" (this is how the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) phrase it).

Does anyone have any idea what this means? Is this lexicographic, numeric or something else? Googling this expression finds these same docs as the main hits, so I am guessing this is not the standard naming.

Comment: my bet on numeric order ( sorted by their score ). I've never heard of an arithmetic order before.

Comment: @georgesl The sorting is of the classes labels, not the probabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is the sorted order of the class labels: if your labels are `["ham", "spam", "eggs"]`, then they sorted to produce `['eggs', 'ham', 'spam']` (available in the `classes_` attribute).

The first column in the output of `decision_function`, `predict_proba` and `predict_log_proba` then corresponds to class `eggs`, the second to `ham` and the third to `spam`. As an exception, when there are two classes, then the `max` of `classes_` is considered the "positive" class and only values for that class are returned.

The formulation "arithmetic order" is a hold-over from the time when class labels had to be integers. I just [changed the wording](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/d2254e4bff3501054851a0f20724a933f10b6683), so the next release will have a clearer description of how this works.

Comment: Just to make it explicit: The sort order is lexicographic, correct?

Comment: @Bitwise: the order is whatever `np.unique` returns, which in turn calls `sorted` for non-numeric objects, and for strings, that means lexicographic (based on Unicode code points, I think).